# How to install .tar.gz/.tar.bz2 packages without root privileges?

Tags: package-management, tar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz  (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

I had already tried many things but none of them worked.
I've tried `tar xzf file.tar.gz`(replacing file by the package name).
I'm using 12.04.1 precise pangolin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untar the file using command

```
 tar xjvf tarball_package.tar.bz2
```

or

```
 tar xzvf tarball_package.tar.gz
```

If there is a .deb(Precompiled binaries) file in the extracted package. You can install it using command `dpkg -i package_name.deb`

If its a source file then you need to compile it using the following commands.

```
./configure 
make
make install
```

For more information read this [Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)